# Play sound at application startup using eventtrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to play a *wav* file once at application startup (`WPF` application `.NET 4.5`). I read a nice way to achieve this is by using `EventTrigger` and a `SoundPlayerAction` like that:

```
<Button Content="Play Sound">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <SoundPlayerAction Source="test.wav" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**How can I trigger this on application startup and not with a button click like in the example above?**

Followup question:

Does playing the sound increase application startup time by the length of the wav file?
(ok, I can test this, but perhaps you know it by heart...)

Comment: i would think the [Loaded event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx) would be where you want to play the audio

Comment: of the window I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example:

```
<Window x:Class="PlaySoundAtStartup.MainWindow"
        ...>

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <SoundPlayerAction Source="test.wav" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Grid />
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Anatoliy, works perfect. Now my application is mooing at startup.

Comment: Just make sure to set "test.wav" as either a resource or add copy if newer, it's set to content and don't copy by default.